# Date field adds a hidden apostrophe

Tags: 8, views

I use [Excel Serialization](https://www.drupal.org/project/xls_serialization) to export views data on Excel. The exported file (xls or xlsx it doesn't matter) adds a hidden apostrophe in the beginning of every date cell ('08/07/2011) which can be seen only on the input line. This leads to wrong column sorting. The cell format is Number instead of Date and this probably causes the problem.

There is a workaround to remove the apostrophes from the whole column, but I want to have the cells without it from the beginning. Is there any way to do this? Maybe by formatting the column before the export? No support from the module maintainers. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know this module, but I guess the leading apostrophe is required by Excel itself: A leading apostrophe in Excel usually means that it should not calculate what entered in the cell as *08 divided by 07 divided by 2011* (0,0000568), but treat the cell value as a string.

Comment: Yes I think you are right!!! But I don't want to treat it as a number nor a text cell but as a date cell, as is. That's the problem...